# Issues with reading words from a text file into 2d Array

Tags: c, arrays, string

I recently started a program in which I have to sort a list of guests, but the overall problem details are irreverent for the issue I'm having.

Well, I want to scan in first and last names from a file SEPARATELY, which I know you do by scanning them as strings. However, we just started using strings and I'm having a little brain fart and I've searched places but I can't figure out how to do so. I'm also having trouble structuring the array inside the for loops. My mind has been totally out of school since Skyrim came out :). Here's the input text file:

```
//First number is the amount of families on the list, second number is the room capacity, ignore that for now.

10 30 

//Format = First Name, Last Name, Number of Family Members (ignore), Priority Level (ignore)

BEN JOHNSON 4 2 

DOUG ESPINOSA 3 2

SARAH TELLINGER 5 3

GRANT THOMPSON 5 2

JENNIFER WEST 7 6

JACKSON JOHNSON 1 5

MARTY MCFLY 4 1

ELIZABETH JAMES 2 6

MICKEY MOUSE 2 4

RAJ SHAH 2 5
```

Here's my code so far: Assume MAX_FAMILY_MEMBERS = 10 and MAX_NAME_LENGTH = 20

```
void Read_First_Name(FILE *ifp, char First_Name[//Assume MAX_FAMILY_MEMBERS is here][MAX_NAME_LENGTH]){

int i, j;

for(i = 0; i < MAX_FAMILY_MEMBERS; i++) 
{
    for(j = 0; j < MAX_NAME_LENGTH; i++) 
    {
        fscanf("%s", First_Name[i][j]);
    }
}}
```

I'm sure this is most likely wrong but I'm quite confused and out of it. If there are any questions about my program please ask.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy if you use fgets with sscanf in one loop like

```
char line[100], firstnames[100][100], famnames[100][100];
int counter=0;

while( fgets(line,100,yourfilepointer) )
  if( sscanf(line,"%s%s",firstnames[counter],famnames[counter])==2 )
    ++counter;
...
while( counter-- )
  printf("%s %s\n",firstnames[counter],famnames[counter]);
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this _without_ sscanf and fgets? We haven't learned either of those in class and he doesn't like us using things we haven't learned :/

Answer (score 0):

I Presume you want to sort the families basing on their priority level. In the code you wrote,

Your fscanf syntax is incorrect. Go through the syntax once more.

```
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_FAMILY_MEMBERS; i++) 
    {
    for(j = 0; j < MAX_NAME_LENGTH; i++) 
    {
    fscanf("%s", First_Name[i][j]);
    }
    }
```

It is good that you want to read line by line (family by family) but how you read each family is improper.

%s format specifier reads an entire string until it encounters a space. 
so that second for loop is very messy.

I will slightly change the code, you can improve on it and write your own logic

```
    #define NUMBEROFFAMILIES 10
    #define FAMILYNAMELENGTH 20

    char firstName[NUMBEROFFAMILIES][FAMILYNAMELENGTH]; // to store first name 
    char secondName[NUMBEROFFAMILIES][FAMILYNAMELENGTH]; // to store second name
    int familtyPriority[NUMBEROFFAMILIES][1]; // to store priority

    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < MAX_FAMILY_MEMBERS; i++){
        fscanf(ifp,"%s",firstName[NUMBEROFFAMILIES]); // read first name
        fscanf(ifp,"%s",secondName[NUMBEROFFAMILIES]); // read second name
        fscanf(ifp,"%d", &j); // Ignore family members count
        fscanf(ifp,"%d", &familtyPriority[NUMBEROFFAMILIES][1]); // family priority
   }
```

EDITED FOR THE NEXT QUESTION

You want to sort based on the priority level.

```
       int familtyPriorityCopy[NUMBEROFFAMILIES][1]; // to store priority
       int familyOrder[NUMBEROFFAMILIES][1]; // to store the proper order.
       // initialize them
       for (i=0;i<NUMBEROFFAMILIES;i++){
          familtyPriorityCopy[i][1] = familtyPriority[i][1];
          familyOrder[i][1] = i;
       }
       // sorting [insertion sort]           
       for (i=1;i<NUMBEROFFAMILIES;i++){
         for (j=0;j<i;j++){
           if (familtyPriorityCopy[j][1] < familtyPriorityCopy[i][1]){
              swap(familtyPriorityCopy[i][1],familtyPriorityCopy[j][1]);
              swap(familyOrder[i][1], familyOrder[j][1]);
           }
         }
       }
```

At the end, familtyPriorityCopy array is sorted. But this is not what is important. familyOrder array is what points to the correct order. We will use this array to print them in the right order.

```
   for(i = 0; i < MAX_FAMILY_MEMBERS; i++){
        printf("%s",firstName[familyOrder[i][1]][1]); // read first name
        printf("%s",secondName[familyOrder[i][1]][1]); // read second name
        printf("%d", familtyPriority[familyOrder[i][1]][1]); // family priority
   }
```

Comment: If you want to read the both first name and second name at a time... read character by character and stop when you encounter the second space. or a simple fscanf(ifp, "%[^0123456789]s", name[xx]); will do ...

Comment: I have another question. I posted an answer with my problem in it.

Comment: Where is the other question you are talking about? I am unable to follow you. Have you been able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
void Read_And_Store(FILE *ifp, int FAMILIES_KNOWN, char First_Name[][MAX_NAME_LENGTH], char Last_Name[][MAX_NAME_LENGTH], int Family_Members[], int Priority[]){
int i;

for(i = 0; i < FAMILIES_KNOWN - 1; i++)
{
    fscanf(ifp, "%s", First_Name[i]);
    fscanf(ifp, "%s", Last_Name[i]);
    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &Family_Members[i]);
    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &Priority[i]);
}}
```

Here's what I did and it works fine when I print it out. However, I've tried a bunch of stuff trying to sort the printed list by priority level, but none of them are successful... any ideas? After I get the sort down the rest is just basic logic and swapping.

Comment: Is the condition in the loop correct. I think with the naming convention you used it may be "for (i=0; i < FAMILIES_KNOWN; i++)"